# Raising error/warning without intteruption in odoo/python

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, odoo

I have a string on errors and I want to just display them in pop-up window.
It's all correct, but I don't want to interrupt the program, when the error string is displayed.
I imported warnings,except_orms but the result is the same.
Even with return {'title':warn.....} is not working
Here is the code:

```
            # raise UserError(_(errorstring))
            # warnings.warn('errorstring')
            # raise Warning(_(errorstring))
            raise except_orm(_('Warning'), (_(errstring)))
```

Is it even possible to have this window without interruption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this if you're looking for on-change warning message:

```
    @api.onchange('field')
    def onchange_field(self):
        return {
                'warning': {'title': _('Warning'), 'message': _('Message needed.'),},
            }
```